# How add sql file in laravel installer

Tags: laravel

I use this package [laravel-installer](https://packagist.org/packages/froiden/laravel-installer) in my project , i see all laravel installer like same , i cant find how to add my sql file in installer someone can help me how to add my sql file in laravel installer .
Thanks in advance

i see all laravel installer like same , i cant find how to add my sql file in installer someone can help me how to add my sql file in laravel installer .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel Web installer checks for the following things and install the application in one go.

1. Check For Server Requirements.
2. Check For Folders Permissions.
3. Ability to set database information.
4. Migrate The Database.
5. Seed The Tables.

The package you using will Run the migration and call the seeder